# Optimize way to store csv data in cassandra for fast retrieval

Tags: csv, cassandra

I have a column of csv data which i want to store it in apache cassandra (**not DATASTAX Version**).

for example my data would contain:

```
val3,val1,val2,val4  
val2,val4,val1,val3
```

i want to process this data and want the output in the following manner :

```
 value       position 
   val1         2,3
   val2         3,1 
   val3         1,4
   val4         4,2
```

Keeping in mind that cassandra doesn't allow for join, order by, group by or where clause(>=, <=) even after making secondary index. So, should i dump it as it is?

So, my question is what are the general practices followed by people to efficiently store the csv data in cassandra?

Is there a stable version (reason being for stable is that i tried few of them but didn't work) of hive-cassandra connector through which we can achieve join, order by, group by or where clause(>=, <=)?

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra benefits from query driven modelling. What's your query? Is it to get the indexes for a value? In that case, create a table like:

```
create table entries(
    value text,
    entry int,
    location int,
    primary key (value, entry))
```

And then read the csv and insert into the table. You can then do

```
select * from entries where value='val1'
```

Alternatively, if you're looking to do arbitrary analytics (ala hadoop), I can highly recommend the spark cassandra connector ot use spark to do the analytics queries. You can even use Spark (or even Spark Streaming) to read in the csv files and do sc.SaveToCassandra to store the results in the cassandra table for quick querying.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector